# Why is PS1 being physically changed in file, against my will by some outside process?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, chromebook, .profile

Really weird thing going on here after [enabling `Linux`](https://chromeunboxed.com/news/chrome-os-beta-channel-linux-apps-update) on my Chromebook. It's not a deal breaker but it's extremely weird. Why is `PS1` always being set to this?

```
\[\033[01;34m\]\u\[\033[00m\]@\[\033[01;32m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[31m\] \[\033[01;34m\]$\[\033[00m\]
```

Even when I use this at the end of `.profile`?

```
export PS1='\[\033[01;34m\]\u\[\033[00m\]@\[\033[01;32m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[31m\]$(__git_ps1 " >> %s") \[\033[01;34m\]$\[\033[00m\] '
```

---

The truly amazing thing is, that wherever I put `export PS1=`, it gets *physically changed in the file* to the first `PS1` entry I mentioned above. Meaning all these possible locations get *actually altered* and put back to the burnt-in `PS1` by some outside process:

- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc`
- `/etc/profile.d/git.sh`

And weirder still! When I create a file called `~/.prompt` for example, and add it to run in either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`, with `source ~/.prompt` then *that* file also gets overwritten.

I've already set `export PROMPT_COMMAND=''` per advise I'd seen, which did not work, but lead me to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11107564/1169705

Only this has worked so far, and I want to know why:

```
function prompt_command {
    export PS1='\[\033[01;34m\]\u\[\033[00m\]@\[\033[01;32m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[31m\]$(__git_ps1 " >> %s") \[\033[01;34m\]$\[\033[00m\] '
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

Comment: You don't need to export PS1: it's a *shell* variable, not an *environment* variable

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have installed `git` which I believe is responsible for
the changes that you see, when it adds `$(__git_ps1 " >> %s")` in the middle
of your PS1 string.

PROMPT_COMMAND works because it is executed later and repeatedly each time
before Bash displays a prompt, so overrides the change.

You should ensure you are setting PS1 after git has done its stuff,
but I cannot tell where it is.

Note : See this
[StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058325/what-is-the-difference-between-ps1-and-prompt-command/11107564#11107564).

Comment: The reason why I am changing `PS1` is because *I* added the `__git_ps1` portion, so I can see what branch of a repository is deployed to whatever directory I'm in. And that link is the one I mentioned also, so, same page.